# An old project doesn't work under ios6.1 simulator anymore after upgrade xcode to 5

Tags: ios, xcode

Hey guys i need some help here. I have been stuck at here for 2 days.
I have an old iOS project which used to work under iOS6.1 simulator. A few days ago I upgraded the Xcode to version 5 to make it support iOS7. Now this project only works under iOS7 simulator. When I try to run it under iOS6.1 simulator, Xcode popups a dialog saying "iOS simulator cannot install this application." It doesn't show any other error.

I compared the build settings of this project with another project which works fine under both iOS 6.1 and 7 simulators but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove application from simulator before build and run it from Xcode.

Comment: If your settings really are the same as the project that does work under 6.1, you should also make certain to do a "clean" before build + installing into the simulator.

Comment: @Michael: I did clean it for many times.

Comment: @DizAsm: After reading your comments I used shell to remove the whole dict(rm -rf *). And now it works! Thank you. Please post ur answer down there and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove application from simulator before build and run it from Xcode.